# I need to make a program that counts out a specific amount of numbers that the user inputs

Tags: c++, numbers

First off let me just say that I have been trying to understand how to do this for hours but I just cannot get it. So any help is appreciated!

So Basically I need to make a program that counts out a specific amount of numbers that the user inputs. An example would be that if the user input 15 my program would go: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,

the list needs to be specifically 10 numbers wide though, it is shown in the images.

Here are examples of successful code & unsuccessful code: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klhCd.jpg)

Here's my code so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "iomanip"

using namespace std; 
int main()
{
int userNum;


cout << "Please insert a number greater than 10 and less than 1000: ";
cin >> userNum;
if (userNum < 1000)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= userNum; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(1) << i << ", ";
    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say it needs to be 10 numbers wide, do you mean you need to print `0000000001`, `0000000002` etc?

Comment: Yup all screenshots seem smae, and the title bar in screenshots say its your homework!

Comment: Where do you check if your number is greater than 10?

Comment: What's your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add to your question (by clicking "edit"): What is the expected result if the input is 11? What is the actual result? Write it down, no screenshots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** Use the `setw(3)`, it will set the width of `cout` print content to 3 as the max value of `userNum` is 999 which is of width = 3.

**second:** Print new line after every 10 items displayed using the following code:

```
if(i%10 == 0) {
   cout << endl; 
}
```

> Final solution is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int userNum;


cout << "Please insert a number greater than 10 and less than 1000: ";
cin >> userNum;
if (userNum >10 && userNum < 1000)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= userNum; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << i << ", ";
        if(i%10 == 0) {
           cout << endl; 
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: ''Here are examples of successful code''  , your code will not out put the same shown in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

Since the program only dealing numbers in between `(10, 1000)` you need to set a width maximum for three digit numbers. i.e. from 11 to 999. 
This will give output what shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klhCd.jpg):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int userNum;
    std::cout << "Please insert a number greater than 10 and less than 1000: ";

    while(std::cin >> userNum )
    {
        if( (10 < userNum) && (userNum < 1000) )
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= userNum; i++)
            {
                std::cout << std::setw(3) << i << ", ";
                if(i % 10 == 0) std::cout << std::endl;

            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "Please insert a number greater than 10 and less than 1000: ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to print 10 numbers in a row and next numbers should appear in the next line.
Please update your for loop as shown below:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= userNum; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(1) << i << ", ";
        if(i % 10 == 0)
        {
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
int userNum;
int i;
cout << "Please insert a number greater than 10 and less than 1000: ";
cin >> userNum;
cout<<"\n";
if (userNum > 10 && userNum < 1000)
{
    for (i = 1; i < userNum; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ", ";
        if(i%10 == 0){ // for newline after each 10th number
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
    cout<< i;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, there is no `,` in the output at the end of each line. So you need a check for `,` too.

```
if (userNum >10 && userNum < 1000)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= userNum; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << i;
        if(i%10 == 0) 
           cout << endl; 
        else
           cout << ",";
    }
}
```